# java call a function with parameters stored in a collection

Tags: function, dynamic, call

I am trying to make my constructor calls dynamic, so if the collection which holds the parameters changes, I only have to adjust the constructor. Is there a way I can interate through the collection while I call the function?

Example:

```
String[] data = new String[] {"first_name", "last_name", "email", "username", "password"};
Person p = new Person(data[0], data[1], data[2], data[3], data[4], data[5])  //dynamic constructor call possible?
```

I need the constructor to recieve the single values so passing a collection is not satisfying.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, your approach is correct

```
    package test;

public class test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        String data[][]=new String[][] {{"A","1","M"},{"B","2","F"},{"C","3","M"}};
        for(String row[] : data) {
            Person p = new Person(row[0],Integer.parseInt(row[1]),row[2].charAt(0));
            System.out.println(p.toString());
        }
}
}
class Person{
    String name;
    int age;
    char gender;

    Person(){}
    Person(String name,int age,char gender){
        this.name=name;
        this.age=age;
        this.gender=gender;
    }
    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Person [name=" + name + ", age=" + age + ", gender=" + gender + "]";
    }
}
```

See if this is what you desired ?